# MoveTargetOutOfBoundsError when trying to perform drag and drop in iframe

Tags: iframe, drag-and-drop, webdriver, watir-webdriver

I'm trying to automate some tests for a web application, and many of the tests require drag and drop inside an `<iframe>`.  I am dragging an anchor from one jspContainer to another within the same `<iframe>`.  I keep getting `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::MoveTargetOutOfBoundsError:` when trying to perform the drag and drop.  I also get the same error when trying to use the `hover` method.  But when I use the `click` method to click on the anchor it works correctly, and I can see the link highlight as if it had been clicked.  Below is some of my code and output through irb.

```
    irb(main):048:0> a = b.frame(:id => "Iframe").link(:text => "anchor")
    => #<Watir::Anchor:0x..f02685d6 located=false selector={:text=>"anchor", :tag_name=>"a"}>
    irb(main):049:0> c = b.frame(:id => "Iframe").div(:id => "drop")
    => #<Watir::Div:0x5ed628c6 located=false selector={:id=>"drop", :tag_name=>"div"}>
    irb(main):050:0> a.wd.location
    => #<struct Selenium::WebDriver::Point x=295, y=339>
    irb(main):051:0> c.wd.location
    => #<struct Selenium::WebDriver::Point x=30, y=329>
    irb(main):052:0> c.style
    => "width: 250px; height: 100px;"
    irb(main):053:0> b.frame(:id => "Iframe").locate
    => #<Watir::FramedDriver:0x24f3738 @element=#<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x..fc6af7d56 id="{11f61368-a4ea-4d
    a9-9084-6307abcda2aa}">, @driver=#<Selenium::WebDriver::Driver:0x..f97d59986 browser=:firefox>>
    irb(main):054:0> a.drag_and_drop_on c
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::MoveTargetOutOfBoundsError: Given coordinates (432, 542) are outside the document.
 Error: MoveTargetOutOfBoundsError: The target location (432, 544) is not on the webpage.
    irb(main):056:0* a.hover
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::MoveTargetOutOfBoundsError: Given coordinates (432, 542) are outside the document.
 Error: MoveTargetOutOfBoundsError: The target location (432, 544) is not on the webpage.
    irb(main):059:0* a.click
    => []
```

One thing I've noticed is when setting the variables `a` and c the output from irb says `located=false`.  But I can use the `exists?`, `click`, and `flash` methods to show that watir-webdriver does know where those elements are.  Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

I'm using watir-webdriver 0.6.2, Firefox 18.0.2, Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: frames are just evil, but some web devs are addicted to them.   Adding webdriver tag since this error comes up from that level.